# Am I calling the constructor or the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

If I have a class called Connection for which I have defined both the copy constructor and the assignment operator=.

When I write the code `Request r2 = r1;` (where `r1` has been defined through the constructor: `Connection r1`), am I calling the copy constructor or the assignment operator=?

Comment: Copy constructor.

Comment: You are calling neither of the two. You are using some constructor or conversion function, not an assignment operator, but it is (likely) not the copy constructor, because `Request` is a different type than `Connection`. Please provide a complete [mre].